# Scraping a page but not the next page

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap a website and able to do but when I click on second page and try to scrap same code is displaying an error.

1. scraps data for the first page.
2. Clicks on 2 page link.
3. Displaying the below error.

> Object variable or with block not set

Website is launched and scraping data in the first page using the below.

```
Dim Shell As Object
Dim IE As Object
Dim linkelement As Object
Dim link As HTMLLinkElement

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each IE In Shell.Windows
    If TypeName(IE.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        IE.Quit
    End If
Next

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

    Dim IntExpl As Object
    Dim HTMLdoc  As HTMLDocument


    Set IntExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IntExpl
        .navigate "http://www.ikea.com/us/en/search/?query=chair"
        .Visible = True
Q:

    Do Until IntExpl.ReadyState = 4

    Loop



    For i = 1 To 25

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = .document.getElementById("txtNameProduct" & i).innerText
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = .document.getElementById("txtPriceProduct" & i).innerText
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = .document.getElementById("txtDescrProduct" & i).innerText

    Next

    End With

    Set HTMLdoc = IntExpl.document

    While j < HTMLdoc.Links.Length And link Is Nothing
        If HTMLdoc.Links(j).innerText = "2" Then Set link = HTMLdoc.Links(j)
        j = j + 1
    Wend
```

This go to the next page of the website

```
    If Not link Is Nothing Then
        link.Focus
        link.Click
    End If

GoTo Q
```